# Rebus with Azure Service Bus, subscribe to an interface

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

I'd like to receive all the messages that are implementing a specific interface:

```
public interface IBusItem
{
    Guid BusItemId { get; }
    DateTime Timestamp { get; }
}
```

For example, I have a message like this:

```
public class SomeMessage : IBusItem
{
    public Guid BusItemId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I have an handler for SomeMessage and another one for IBusItem.
If in the receiver I do:

```
bus.Subscribe<SomeMessage>();
```

then BOTH handlers are called.

But if I want to subscribe just to IBusItem:

```
bus.Subscribe<IBusItem>();
```

then no handler is called

Is it possible to subscribe to a base interface/class using Rebus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to subscribe to a base interface/class using Rebus?

Unfortunately, no.

While Rebus has [polymorphic dispatch](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Polymorphic-message-dispatch), this only applies to when a message has been received and is to be dispatched to handlers.

So if you want to receive all concrete types that implement `IBusItem`, you need to call `await bus.Subscribe<ConcreteBusItem>()` for each of them.

Comment: No problem. It can be done by scanning the assembly and register all the classes that implements IBusItem